# How to make UITextView from scratch?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

As I understand, [Apple does not provide the source code for UIKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181024/where-are-the-uikit-framework-implementation-files-located). In order to answer [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620291/how-to-make-a-vertical-uitextview-by-subclassing-it-from-uiscrollview-in-swift), though, I am trying to understand how `UITextView` works (or could be made to work) under the hood.

How would I set up a minimal `UITextView` myself?

I see from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/) that it inherits from `UIScrollView` so I assume that I would start there.

```
import UIKit
class MyUITextView: UIScrollView {

    // ???
}
```

Again looking at the text view docs, it looks like I would need to at a minimum implement the [`init`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITextView/initWithFrame:textContainer:) method and the [`text`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/text) property. (I can ignore all the editing aspects and formatting attributes for now.)

The `init` method takes the following form:

```
init(frame frame: CGRect, textContainer textContainer: NSTextContainer?)
```

So I would also need a property for an [`NSTextContainer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextContainer_Class/). This [`TextKit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html) component works together with [`NSTextStorage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextStorage_Class/) and [`NSLayoutManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSLayoutManager_Class/) so I need to work those in somewhere, too. I could set the `NSTextStorage` with the `text` property but I really don't know how `NSLayoutManager` would interact here.

Has anyone (outside of Apple) done this before? Is this a simple enough question to answer here or would the answer be to long?

**Update:**

This question shows my latest attempt: [How to Initialize NSTextStorage with a String in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796174/how-to-initialize-nstextstorage-with-a-string-in-swift)

Comment: Why are you doing this? Does a category not do what you want?

Comment: TextMate is an open-source app that implements its own text view, if I'm not mistaken. It's on GitHub.

Comment: @Sirens I'm doing this in order to eventually answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620291/how-to-make-a-vertical-uitextview-by-subclassing-it-from-uiscrollview-in-swift

Comment: @JoshCaswell You're right. [TextMate source](https://github.com/textmate/textmate) in Objective C is on GitHub. I couldn't find a custom UITextView, though.

Comment: Extra user defined methods can be added using categories.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely complicated. I've had to reimplement a subset of UILabel before, and that was tricky. I think the first thing you should think about is what level you're interested in working in. At it's most basic, `UITextView` is responsible for manipulating a bitmap graphics context and turning a string into pixels on your screen. That in itself is a pretty big challenge, and if you want to reimplement that functionality from scratch you're going to be busy for a while.

At a higher level, `UITextView` does things like breaking text up into lines, displaying different fonts; higher still and you have things like the [UITextInput Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/index.html), which handles letting the user enter and manipulate the text view's contents.

In terms of implementation details, those obviously aren't available. The closest we can get is a [header dump](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UITextView.h), which is interesting but might not tell us much.

Until iOS7 and TextKit, text rendering was actually handled by WebKit, which means the implementation is potentially more of a mess for having undergone that transition.

Anyway, some things to point you in the right (or at least *a*) direction:

- [NSAttributedString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html), especially the [UIKit Additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011688), which let you actually blit text into a graphics context;
- [Introducing TextKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/IntroToTextKit/Introduction/Intro.html), some sample code from WWDC13 (there's an accompanying video as well)
- [Intro to Text Kit](http://www.appcoda.com/intro-text-kit-ios-programming-guide/) from AppCoda.

I apologize that this answer probably isn't as useful as I'd intended. Basically: this is a really big question; it's probably *multiple* really big questions.

Comment: All I want it to do is render text on a view with the appropriate line breaks and scrolling. It seems to me like TextKit should be able to handle the rendering and line wrapping and subclassing UIScrollView should be able to handle the scrolling. I keep hoping someone will tell me that a basic solution isn't that complicated, but you are probably right. Anyway, +1 for your input. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below sources to understand what happens under the hood. Apple'e implementation need not be the same though.

https://github.com/BigZaphod/Chameleon/blob/master/UIKit/Classes/UITextView.h
https://github.com/BigZaphod/Chameleon/blob/master/UIKit/Classes/UITextView.m

Comment: Some thoughts after reading through the code: These didn't use any TextKit components that I could see. I wonder if they are implementing a pre iOS 7 version of UITextView that didn't use TextKit. I got a little lost in the details (like why `interface UIScrollView` is used rather than subclassing UIScrollView) but I will continue to study this.

Comment: Yes, It is pretty ios7

Comment: Chameleon is an older project, dating back I think to iOS 4/5? So it doesn't use any of the new TextKit stuff.